# How to detect comma vs semicolon separation in a file before reading it?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr, readr

I'm using readr and purrr to map reduce through a set of filenames, read the files and combine them into one single tibble.

The data comes from an external partner. Most files are semicolon separated and can be read using read_csv2, but some comma separated files are spread into the set of files.

I'm wondering what could be the simplest way to quickly detect if the file is a comma or semicolon separated file before reading it, so I could either apply read_csv or read_csv2 ?

My code is as below, and uses purrr map reduce functions, as well as a formula for reading each file and transforming content before binding the results into a single dataset.

```
ndr_path <- "C:/Data"

file_names <- file.path(ndr_path, list.files(ndr_path, "01.b forecasts 202[1-9][0-9]{4,4}\\.csv"))

data <- file_names[1] %>%
  map(~ {
    read_csv2(.x) %>%
      select(Product, "Product Description", Date, "NDR") %>%
      mutate(VMIDate = as.Date(gsub("^.*(\\d{8})\\.csv$", "\\1", .x), format="%Y%m%d")) %>%
      mutate(NDR = as.numeric(NDR))
  }) %>%
  reduce(rbind)
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'd probably take it out of the `map` because you're going to need an `if` statement in there somewhere which will get confusing. If you know that you can always expect more than one column, just read in the first row and see how many columns you get. You can do something like `df = read_delim(.x, n_max = 0, delim = ",") ; df = ifelse(ncol(df)>1, df, read_delim(.x, n_max = 0, delim = ";")`.

Comment: Is `data.table::fread()` an option for you for the importing part? In the vast majority of cases, it reliably recognises the delimiter by itself.

Comment: As mentioned by Marco_CH, data.table::fread() is reliable in many cases. But its also advisable to write a function to check the number of rows/cols the dataframe holds and if it does not meet your mininum row/col then use another separator in the loop.

Ex: 
1) Read csv
2) Check nos of rows/cols
3) If OK, proceed
4) If Not OK, change sep and repeat #1
5) Merge all df into master_df

Comment: Sam, Marco, thanks for your inputs. I did not know about the fread function, very useful. I may in the end create two sets of file names, one for comma separated, and one for semicolon separated files and process them in two times.

Comment: Inspired by the fread comments, I finally replaced the read_csv2 by a read_delim, and used the guess_delim function found in package hdd (it uses fread). `read_delim(.x, delim=guess_delim(.x))`  instead of `read_csv2(.x)`. It works find and I managed to keep everything in the tight map/reduce form. Thank you all for your help.